# Database Server Node vs. Database Connection Node

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, sql-server, arccatalog

What are the main differences between the Server Node and the Connection Node?

The only difference I have been able to find is that the Server Node is intended for administrative tasks while the Connection Node is used when accessing data on one geodatabase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This documentation gives a pretty good description of what each node is for, and it confirms what you mentioned. The Database Server node is for creating the geodatabase and administrative tasks (for SQL Server Express), and the Database Connection node is for creating/editing/viewing data.

[A quick tour of setting up and using database servers](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/A_quick_tour_of_setting_up_and_using_database_servers/018t00000018000000/)

> Anyone who has an Advanced or Standard license of ArcGIS for Desktop,
>   ArcGIS Engine with the Geodatabase Update option, or ArcGIS for Server
>   at the Workgroup level can set up and use an instance of SQL Server
>   Express (a database server) to store geodatabases.
>
> You can set up a database server to use yourself, or you can add other
>   users to the database server to allow them to access geodatabases on
>   the database server. In most cases, the person who sets up the
>   database server is the server administrator. That person is
>   responsible for access to and maintenance of the database server.

---

> **Set Up**
>
> To set up a database server, install SQL Server Express and enable it
>   to store geodatabases, add a connection to the SQL Server instance
>   under the Database Servers node in the Catalog, and create
>   geodatabases.

---

> **Making Connections**
>
> There are two ways to access the geodatabases on a database server
>   from ArcGIS for Desktop: through the **Database Server node** in the
>   Catalog window or through the **Database Connections node**.
>
> **Server and geodatabase administrators must create connections under**
>   **the Database Servers node when they want to perform administrative**
>   **tasks such as creating a backup of a geodatabase or altering user**
>   **permissions.** You already added a database server connection to create
>   geodatabases and add any logins needed. Therefore, when you restart
>   ArcMap or ArcCatalog, your database server connection is already
>   there. To reconnect to it, follow the steps in Connecting to a
>   database server.
>
> **Users who only need to create, edit, or read data from the**
>   **geodatabases can make a connection under the Database Connections node**
>   **to a specific geodatabase.** This is also necessary when running many
>   geoprocessing tools or if you will be publishing services. The server
>   administrator should provide these users with the information they
>   need to create a database connection or create a connection file for
>   them to use. See Preconfiguring connection files for more information.

Answer (score 1):

My experience has been that the Database Server node is explicitly for use of connecting to spatially enabled "Express" editions of RDBMS where as the Database Connection Node is used to conect to Enterprise RDBMS like SQL or Oracle (spatially enabled or not).

[What are Database Servers](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/What_are_database_servers_in_ArcGIS/018t0000000p000000/)

[Quick Tour of Administering SDE gdbs](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/A_quick_tour_of_administering_ArcSDE_geodatabases_with_ArcGIS_for_Desktop/01900000000m000000/)